# How to output only the result of a command to file?

Tags: bash, stdout

I’m trying to determine the IP of an endpoint and write it to a file. 
When I type:

```
dig +short endpoint.com
```

at a command prompt
I get:

```
10.50.4.235
```

However, when I try to write that output to a file using this command in a script:

```
dig +short $EndpointName > /home/ec2-user/endpoint-ip.txt
```

I get this in the file:

```
endpoint.com
10.50.4.235
```

It is including the value of the variable, I would prefer to just have the result (ip only). Thank you much for any help.

Comment: Try `host endpoint.com`. Maybe you need to use `grep` to filter it better.

Comment: some commands operate differently when stdout is the terminal or file versus a pipe. Try `dig +short endpoint.com` and  `dig +short endpoint.com | cat`

Comment: You need to quote "$EndpointName".

Comment: You must be doing something else that you haven't mentioned - `dig +short 'endpoint.com' > endpoint-ip.txt` writes just the IP address to the file. Are you sure the contents of `$EndpointName` are as expected? Are you perhaps appending (`>>`) rather than overwriting (`>`)? What's your `dig -version`?

Comment: Thank you - this is the whole contents of my script:

    `#!/bin/bash`

    `EndpointName=$(</home/ec2-user/EndpointName.txt)`

    `dig +short $EndpointName > /home/ec2-user/endpoint-ip.txt`

the dig version is:
DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.55.amzn1
no append, just one >

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="endpoint.com"
dig +short $URL  > dig-ip.txt
```

The result in the file only gives the IP.

```
cat dig-ip.txt
23.239.26.161
```

Would have to revise as you are assigned the value to the variable $EndPointName.

Comment: thanks I tried using " around `EndpointName` but script failed - error was "failed to run command EndpiontName...etc"

Comment: The variable $ EndpointName where you are taking the values, some file or the result of another command? @kavise

Answer (score 0):

Try to revese grep of endpoint.com

```
dig +short endpoint.com | grep -v endpoint.com > endpoint-ip.txt
```

Comment: thank you - this produced the same result - two entries in the file:
FQDN and
IP

Comment: Try change output file name, maybe something else is writing to the file. Also, how many lines does EndpointName.txt contain ?